# Dice Rolling Program

Tags: java, dice

I have put together the general sense of this program, I just need help with the "smaller or larger" portion, which is keeping it from being finished. I do know that "<==>" is not viable; that is there as a placeholder until I know what to put there. Should I put two lines? One for "<=" and one for ">=" or some other method?

**The Question:**

Write a program that rolls a dice (but hide the number from player) and then ask user enter a number in range of 1 - 6. If player enters same number of computer rolled, then the player earns $10. If player enters a number that is smaller or larger by 1, then the player earns $3. If player enters a number that is smaller or larger by 2, then the player earns $1. Player has to pay $3 dollar to play once. Make a MatchDice game. Hint: Use the Math.random() method to calculate a random value.

**My Code:**

```
import java.util.*;

public class RollDice {

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    Random dice = new Random();

    // Generate the random number, between 1 and 6
    int randomValue = (int)(Math.random()*6) + 1;
    int dealerValue = (int)(Math.random()*6) + 1;

    System.out.println("Dealer rolled a dice and here is your turn.");
    System.out.print("Enter a number : ");
    int randomValue = input.nextInt();

    if(randomValue == dealerValue)
        System.out.println("Dealer's number was " + randomValue);
        System.out.println("You won $10 ");
    else if(randomValue == dealerValue <==> 1)
        System.out.println("Dealer's number was " + randomValue);
        System.out.println("You won $3 ")
    else if(randomValue == dealerValue <==> 2)
        System.out.println("Dealer's number was " + randomValue);
        System.out.println("You won $1 );
    else
        System.out.println("You lost $3 ");
}
}
```

Comment: Are you asking how to check if a value is equal to another +/- some value?

Comment: `dice` is unused. Also, there's too much copypasta — maybe you need to go through a good book about programming in general

Comment: also I smell this is a homework

Comment: if you are satisfied with the solution, mark the answer as accepted

Answer (score 3):

Use `Math.abs(a - b)`, where `a` is user number and `b` is ... OK, you know.

## Update

Here is complete solution, errors fixed and repetitions minimized.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

class Ideone
{
    static Random rnd = new Random();

    static int dice() {
        return rnd.nextInt(6) + 1;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        int dealerValue = dice();

        System.out.print(
            "Dealer rolled a dice and here is your turn.\n" +
            "Enter a number: ");

        int userValue = Integer.parseInt(input.readLine());

        int difference = Math.abs(randomValue - userValue);

        int profit =
            difference == 0 ? 10 :
            difference == 1 ? 3 :
            difference == 2 ? 1 :
            -3;

        System.out.println("Dealer's number was " + dealerValue);
        System.out.println("You " + ((profit >= 0) ? "won" : "lost") + " $" + Math.abs(profit));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you need to add braces in conditional statement. This code won't even compile!

```
if(randomValue == dealerValue) {
    System.out.println("Dealer's number was " + randomValue);
    System.out.println("You won $10 ");
}
else if(Math.abs(randomValue - dealerValue) == 1) {
    System.out.println("Dealer's number was " + randomValue);
    System.out.println("You won $3 ")
}
else if(Math.abs(randomValue - dealerValue) == 2) {
    System.out.println("Dealer's number was " + randomValue);
    System.out.println("You won $1 );
}
else
    System.out.println("You lost $3 ");
```

The "else" doesn't need braces, because it contains only one expression.
EDIT:
I forgot about the question - you can compute the absolute value of a difference between random and selected value and check whether it is equal to one or two.

Comment: @SargeBorsch Little distraction from a phone and I forgot about finishing question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Probably you wanted to write something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    // Generate the random number, between 1 and 6
    int dealerValue = (int)(Math.random()*6) + 1;

    System.out.println("Dealer rolled a dice and here is your turn.");
    System.out.print("Enter a number : ");
    int inputValue = scanner.nextInt();

    if(inputValue == dealerValue) {
        System.out.println("Dealer's number was " + dealerValue);
        System.out.println("You won $10 ");
    }
    else if(Math.abs(dealerValue - inputValue) == 1) {
        System.out.println("Dealer's number was " + dealerValue);
        System.out.println("You won $3 ");
    }
    else if(Math.abs(dealerValue - inputValue) == 2) {
        System.out.println("Dealer's number was " + dealerValue);
        System.out.println("You won $1 ");
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Dealer's number was " + dealerValue);
        System.out.println("You lost $3 ");
    }

}
```

You don't need dice variable at all, because you don't use it. You also don't need two variables initialized with random number, one is enough.